# Meaning of "Roccamonfina"

Tags: word-meaning, translation, regional, etymology, english-comparison

I am hoping to visit Roccamonfina and have been trying to figure out precisely what this name means---but without success. (Perhaps *fina* is a person's name, and does not mean "fine.")

Can someone tell me the literal meaning of "Roccamonfina"?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Name Roccamonfina comes from Latin: *Roccae Monfinum* which means "rocca della mia Fina", Fina was how it was used to refer to mountain Santa Croce: **Monte Fino**

Back in time, roman emperor Decio followed his lover **Fina** there so he built a fortress, a **rocca**: Rocca della Mia Fina": *Roccae Monfinum* in Latin, the fortress of my Fina.

> Una famosa leggenda vuole Roccamonfina fondata dall’imperatore romano
> Decio, rifugiatosi in queste terre per inseguire la sua amata Fina, in
> onore della quale avrebbe fatto costruire, nel 250 d. C. una Rocca,
> cioè la “Rocca della Mia Fina” . La coincidenza di date fra leggenda e
> tradizione, il conforto di studi storici,archeologici e numismatici
> avvalorano l’ipotesi che Roccamonfina sia nata intorno al III sec. D.
> C. per una naturale fusione di genti autoctone di origine aurunca con
> altre di origine romane, fuggite per sottrarsi alle persecuzioni
> contro i cristiani.

Sources:

- https://www.ganapoletano.it/archemail/arche9/0roccamonfina.htm
- **rocca**, **roccae** latin words: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rocca#Latin

---

## Origin of Rocca Monfina

Rocca Monfina was founded by 10 Roman families which moved away from the dangerous life in Rome to these mountains, together with the brother of the emperor [Filippo Arabo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filippo_l%27Arabo) called Teles, and his daughter called **Fina** looking for a safer place to live.

Source: [La sede degli Aurunci popoli antichissimi dell'Italia.- Girolamo Perrotta 1737 - Chapter: Della Fondazione di Roca Monfina - Page 91](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_HlYTEfl86nIC/page/n128/mode/1up)

Then [Decius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decius) (whose real name was: Gaius Messius Quintus Traianus) Decio revolted against *Philip the Arab* and ruled from 249 to June 251 (c. 1 year and 9 months).

[image: Decius]

Decio looked for her beloved Fina until he found her in that land.

In her honor, he wanted to build a castle, a **rocca**, named **Di Fina**, o **de Monte di Fina**.

Source: [La sede degli Aurunci popoli antichissimi dell'Italia.- Girolamo Perrotta 1737 - Chapter: Della Fondazione di Roca Monfina - Page 91](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_HlYTEfl86nIC/page/n128/mode/1up)

> la solita usurpazione dell'Imperio di que'tempi fatta da Decio: l'aver
> cercata indi il medesimo Decio quella gente, tra la quale era la sua
> sospirata Fina: e l'averla finalmente qui ritrovata, ove a memoria di
> quella volle, che una Rocca sopranomata di Fina, o de Monte di Fina,
> vi fosse edificata.

[image]

## ROCCAMONFINA

*Veritas temporis filia*

Comment: Did the Roman emperor speak Italian? In other words, even if supported by Wikipedia, this seems a folk etymology.

Comment: @egreg Wikipedia is not a source for back up and "Roccae Monfinum" is not italian.

Comment: I was obviously referring to “rocca della mia Fina”, of which I doubt quite a lot.

Comment: Can you add some (reliable) source, please?

Comment: This is meaningless. Decius was emperor for just a couple of years; I doubt that among fighting the Goths, persecuting Christians, quarrelling with the Senate and building baths in Rome, he would have found time to dedicate a fortress to a lover. But the main thing is that _rocca_ or _roccae_ isn't a Latin word. “Rocca della mia Fina”, if anything, would be something like “oppidum meae Finae”. So, do we have an actual source?

Comment: Thank for confirming that _rocca_ is definitely not a (classical) Latin word. The very webpage you quote says that it is a very late loanword, “First attested in a document from France dating to 767 CE”, quite later than Decius.

Comment: @egreg Italian phrase shows the meaning, not the language spoken at that time, obviusly.

Comment: @DaG He found time to dedicate a fortress to a lover, indeed.

Comment: Do you really think that a 18th-century “Digressione apologetica” is a valid source? Are you experienced in research? For instance, who would this “Teles”, brother of emperor Philip and father of “Fina”, would be? History books should cover him, if he were a historical figure.

Comment: Ok, let me be constructive rather than just criticize. While, if Teles and Fina where real historical persons, they would appear in modern history books, you've however made an interesting discovery, that is, that this legend about a woman beloved by Decius dates at least to the 18th century. It would be interesting to understand if it is even older than that.